# Exchange 2013 Certificate replacement

Tags: ssl-certificate, exchange-2013

I have an Exchange 2013 server which works just fine (almost) with all the basic functions  and it uses a SAN certificate from GoDaddy.

I will have to add a new name to the cert so I will have to re-key it and re-apply the cert to the mail server. I would like to know if there is any risk I should be aware of before doing this change.

For example, do you think there will be any issues with clients using outlook anywhere? Or mobile clients (mostly IOS/Android)? Would they notice the change in the cert and start complaining?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As long as certificate:

1) came from trusted issuer

2) has valid names

3) is time valid

there will no issues with clients. They do not remember the certificate, it is checked each time the server is accessed.